# Tracking changes on specific checkbox in a group of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I track an specific checkbox in a checkbox group is checked and unchecked event?

For example I need to check the checked and unchecked event of only the checkbox with value of `map`

```js
$('input:checkbox[name=proj]').on('change', function(){
if($(this.value=='map').is(':checked')){
        console.log('Map id Checked');
    }
    else{}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="proj" value="map">map
<input type="checkbox" name="proj" value="app">app
<input type="checkbox" name="proj" value="nap">nap
```

Comment: "cheked and uncheched event of only the chekbox with value of map" -- So you want the other checkboxes to be unclickable or just not logged when clicked?

Comment: No I actually need to do the same logic for other checkboxes as well but I need to understand how does it work for at least one of them first

Comment: The main issue you're going to have with this is not telling them apart (you can tell them apart by position or by value), but rather than you have given elements that are expressly intended to be independent the same name.  These are not radio boxes, give them different names.  If they are intended to allow selection between three alternatives, use a radio group instead

Comment: `$('input:checkbox[name=proj]:nth-child(1)').on('change', event => event.target.checked? console.log("map is checked"):null );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that you want ?

```js
$('input:checkbox[name="proj"]').on('change', function(){

  if($(this).attr("value")=="map")  // only "map" can alert!
        alert('Map id : ' + $(this).attr("value") + ' is ' +
            
            ($(this).prop("checked") ? "Checked" : "UnChecked")
            
            );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="proj" value="map">map
<input type="checkbox" name="proj" value="app">app
<input type="checkbox" name="proj" value="nap">nap
```

Comment: Thanks Serhat but this is alerting on all the chekboxes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[name="proj"]').on("change",función(){
    if($(this).val()=='map' && $(this).is(':checked'){ 
         console.log('Map id Checked'); 
     } else{
     }
 });
```